# How to let my rx stream react if my subscription is disposed?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have a `Flowable` stream that concatenates multiple streams together:

```java
  Flowable
    .empty()
    .concatWith(longOperationA())
    .concatWith(longOperationB())
    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
      // some cleanup tasks
      return Flowable.error(throwable);
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(mySubscriber);
```

Both `longOperationA()` and `longOperationB()` emit items.
Regarding what circumstances arise (an error occurs or `mySubscriber` gets
disposed), I want to let my stream act differently. The error case is covered
by the `onErrorResumeNext()` callback, but not the case when `mySubscriber`
becomes disposed.

**How can I change my stream to do another task when the subscriber is disposed of?**

To give more context about this, I have tried `doOnCancel()`:

```java
Flowable
  .concatWith(longOperationA())
  .concatWith(longOperationB())
  .doOnCancel(() -> {
    // some cleanup tasks
  })
  .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> { ...
```

However, `doOnCancel()` doesn't only get called when `mySubscription` becomes disposed,
but also when `longOperationA()` (and `longOperationB() respectively) is finished.

Is there any other way to let my stream react to the `dispose` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doOnDispose` for this:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doOnDispose-io.reactivex.functions.Action-

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.